# How to save " \\n " when removing " \n " in string

Tags: python, string

```
>>> b = 'first \\n second \n third \\n forth \n fifth \\n'
>>> print(b)
first \n second 
 third \n forth 
 fifth \n
```

b to wanted result,
print( result )
`first \n second  third \n forth  fifth \n`
result = 'first \n second  third \n forth  fifth \n'
how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\n` is **an** escape character, which indicates a line break, while `\\n` is a **backslash** and a **letter n**, which will not be affected when you delete `\n`:

```
>>> b = 'first \\n second \n third \\n forth \n fifth \\n'
>>> b.replace('\n', '')
'first \\n second  third \\n forth  fifth \\n'
```

This example may make you realize the difference between them:

```
>>> len('\n')
1
>>> list('\n')
['\n']
>>> len('\\n')
2
>>> list('\\n')
['\\', 'n']
```